# Which e-commerce platform you prefer for developing e-commerce website

Tags: magento-1.9

Which e-commerce platform you prefer for developing e-commerce website

Comment: if you go and ask to `FC Barcelona` players that which sports do you want to play, will they tell anything other than `soccer` ?....   , google will give you an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I am considering that you want to make choice between Magento 1.x and Magento 2.x.

I would prefer to go with Magento 2.x (latest) because it has many enhancements and new features.

Also, official support for Magento 1.x will end after November 2018. So it is better to avoid building a new website using Magento 1.x.

Some of the improved features of Magento 2.x are given below:

- Magento 2 officially supports latest PHP versions including PHP 7.
- Varnish cache comes by default with Magento 2, hence store owners do not need to install any third party extension for caching.
- It comes with the Improved process of browser caching for static content.
- What is also good is that with Magento 2 you do not need to contact your developers every time you want to add or remove the columns on the orders or customers management grid, you can simply choose the required columns from the available list in the admin panel.
- Checkout steps have been improved and now it is easier for users to navigate. Magento 2 can automatically find the existing registered customers by analyzing their email address.

Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: what are the many enhancements of Magento 2? As it stands today, Magento 1 is more stable than Magento 2.

Comment: You are right that currently Magento 1 is more stable than Magento 2, but Magento 2 is still improving, while development for Magento 1 has been stopped and its support will stop soon. That's why I would recommend Magento 2.